# Over Preparing a Query

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if one should go the extra mile in over preparing their queries.

For example, a query that takes user input to make a request on the database.

```
if(is_int($id)) {
     $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

vs

```
if(is_int($id)) {
     $mysqli->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = '%d'",$id));
}
```

Comment: Just use prepared statements (PDO, in the PHP world) and stop worrying about SQL injection.

Comment: I would use PDO from the Get Go but I am using Wordpress which already comes with it's own database class. Which sadly requires me to prepare "some" queries.

Comment: Those examples are both safe as your checking that `$id` is a integer tho if its not then the `if` will be passed... would the next part throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three methods to avoid SQL injections: escaping, preparing and typing. Your example uses typing: it ensures that your variable is an integer and, thus, safe. You do not *need* to prepare this statement as you will never encounter an SQL injection with *this* particular piece of code.